# Adb push/push requires an argument

Tags: adb

when i use ‘**adb push**’ command in window10 cmd, it fail with this sentence.
“**adb.exe: push requires an argument**”
What should i do? I wanna give more information, but it’s classifide.

Comment: The error message says it: You did not provide an argument to `adb push`. You need to write what you want to push and to which destination.

Answer (score 6):

If you are trying to push a folder on Windows and you have a backslash at the end, delete it and try the "adb push" again.
You should type some start letters and press the Tab key to let it fill in the url for you inside ' ' or " ". Then if it has a backslash \ at the end, delete it.